# Why is timeAgo returning null?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-8, alpine.js

I am trying to get the update time iteratively whenever the dropdown opens but it is returning me `null`. how to make sure `onchange` event is triggered correctly.

This is what I have tried so far:

```html
<x-nav-dropdown :text="$notificationIcon" :title="text('nav_notifications')" dropdownClass="notifications-dropdown" align="right"> 
  @forelse(Auth::user()->notifications as $notification)
  <x-dropdown-item :route="$notification->data['link']" :title="text($notification->data['link_title'])" onchange="getTime()" x-data="{timeAgo : 'null', getTime() {this.timeAgo = moment('{{ $notification->created_at->format('c') }}').locale('{{ str_replace('_', '-', cur_lang()->slug) }}').fromNow();} }" >
    <span style="display: inline-block;">{{ text($notification->data['subject']) }}</span>
    <time style="float: right;" x-text= timeAgo> </time>

    </span>
    
    <br/>
    <small>{{ array_key_exists('data', $notification->data) && !empty($notification->data['data']) ? new \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString(vsprintf(text($notification->data['message']), $notification->data['data'])) : text($notification->data['message']) }}</small>
  </x-dropdown-item>
  @empty
  <x-dropdown-item route="#" :title="text('notifications_none')">
    {{ text('notifications_none') }}
  </x-dropdown-item>
  @endforelse
</x-nav-dropdown>
```

For example desired out should be:

```
"x"-minuets ago
```

Am I doing it right? Can I call the `onchange` event into bootstrap tags? Any kind of help in right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure If I understand you correctly but this code snippet is from blade.php file and I am writing php code enclosed in php tags where it is necessary rest its HTML.  `x-nav-dropdown` this is the custom bootstrap component and inside there is alpine `x-data` where I am defining the function `getTime` this also refers to my question where i asked   is it right to call `onchange` event into bootstrap tag. I hope it clarifies now.

Comment: probably fix that HTML first, you have a `</span>` that's tied to nothing. (did your editor not warn you about this? If not, you want to install whatever plugin exists for it to lint/check alpine-enriched html)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for indicating that, it was typo and surprisingly my editor didn't catch it. I am just a beginner.